# Use linq query to display literal in repeater rather than database value C# web app

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query below that I bind to a repeater in c# Web app. I would like to display, "ALL" in the casenumber column if it has a value of 0(zero). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

```
      var linqQuery = from nn in interestList
                        join KY in interestTypeList on nn.InterestTypeCd equals KY.InterestTypeCd
                        where (nn.ArrearAuditID == Convert.ToInt32(AdminBasePage.ArrearAuditId))
                        orderby nn.InterestStartDate descending
                        select
                            new
                            {
                                nn.CaseNumber,
                                //Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(nn.GrantAmount),2)
                                InterestPercent = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(nn.InterestPercent), 2),
                                KY.InterestTypeDescription,
                                nn.SubAccountTypeCd,
                                InterestStartDate = nn.InterestStartDate.Value.Month + "/" + nn.InterestStartDate.Value.Year,
                                //nn.InterestStartDate,
                                InterestEndDate = nn.InterestEndDate.Value.Month + "/" + nn.InterestEndDate.Value.Year,
                                //nn.InterestEndDate,                        
                                InterestStartDateOriginal = nn.InterestStartDate,
                                InterestEndDateOriginal = nn.InterestEndDate,
                                nn.PaymentInterestID  //This field not in repeater but needed to bind 
                            };

      // Execute the linq query and databind
        linqQuery = linqQuery.OrderByDescending(y => y.InterestStartDateOriginal);
        InterestListRepeater.DataSource = linqQuery;
        InterestListRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Chris - not sure what you mean by "the rest of the select isn't actually removed" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important bits:

```
var linqQuery = from nn in interestList
                ...
                select new
                {
                    CaseNumber = nn.CaseNumber == 0 ?
                        "All" :
                        nn.CaseNumber.ToString(),
                    ...
                };
```

Comment: Seems to answer the question perfectly... Though maybe a `...` in the code to indicate that the rest of the select isn't actually removed. Its the only thing I can find objectionable...

Comment: if this LINQ to Entities: _LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression_

Comment: @Grundy: Didn't consider that, but hopefully the variable names containing `List` is an indication that this is a Linq-to-Objects query.